# How to check google font load time

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, google-font-api

I want to use a google font(Roboto/Open Sans).
Where I can check which font taking much time to load?
As I remember google.com/fonts had this feature earlier: http://prntscr.com/ekyy1d but now I can't find it there...

Comment: The answwer of @MichealCoker is working as charm on your browser. But you can test your site online and from different locations with some services like [this](https://www.giftofspeed.com/).

Answer (score 2):

you can use your browser's dev tools to get the file size and how long it took to download from the CDN.

This is chrome, under the "network" tab in dev tools https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu96t.png

Comment: The fonts aren't downloaded if you already have them locally so it makes this method redundant if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't able to find the gauges but there is an indication of the speed in the lower right menu bar.

[screenshot of menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFT5r.png)